# Tips on improving performance of fuse based file system

Tags: performance, filesystems, fuse

I am comparing fusepy , Java based NFS server and native. I see that native file system is 4 times faster and surprisingly Java based NFS server is twice faster compared fusepy based loopback system. Any tips to improve the performance of file systems written based on fusepy or fuse-python. I am running them on linux kernel 2.6.9 and fuse binding version is 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the python code is blocking anywhere?